# Failed to find data-block with angular-blocks

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use '**angular-blocks**' but I am receiving a warning.

My template (/fc-layout.html) has this code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/fc-layout.html">
    <div data-block="fc">
        <p>:fc</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

and my custom page (/views/fc1.html) has the next code:

```
<div data-extend-template="/fc-layout.html">
    <div data-block="fc">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting empty pages and **"Failed to find data-block=fc in /fc-layout.html"** message in console.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes.
1. In fc-layout.html remove script tags (i had same problem, this solved)
2. Ensure proper path in fc1.html (right now i think your path is wrong)